# PostgreSQL Select acorss tables

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have very little experience with PostgreSQL and looking for a way using pgadmin to list out the rows across tables with foreign keys so that I can quickly update some records without doing this via a webapp.

All my tables are prefixed with app

I can `select` * from one table, but don't know what I'm doing beyond that to get the related table data.

```
SELECT app_choice.choice_text, app_choice.question_id, app_choice_choice_value
FROM app_choice;
INNER JOIN app_projectquestionnairequestion
ON app.questionnaire.id = app_projectquestionnairequestion.id;
```

Some my `choice` table is linked to my `projectquestionnairequestion` table. So basically every question in `projectquestionnairequestion` has a related choice in the `choice` table.

But not all questions have a choice available so i need a way to list all the questions to let me add a choice to it?

Sorry for the bad explanation. It's hard to explain when I dont know the terms

Thanks

Comment: Please include a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I have updated the question, so hopefully gives a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a comment that doesn't fit in the comments section. Don't upvote it since I'll remove it.

Your syntax is a bit wrong, but you are not too far from it. Also, you should use "table aliases" as well (`c` and `q` below). Your query could look like:

```
SELECT
  c.choice_text, c.question_id, c.choice_value,
  q.name -- this would be the "name" column of the second table
FROM app_choice c
INNER JOIN app_projectquestionnairequestion q
ON q.id = c.question_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, ill take a look at the table aliases and see if i can work this out.